# Summarize rows with same values on specific columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

For a college project I work with the Johns Hopkins Coronavirus COVID-19 dataset: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19. What I am trying is to make the dataset simpler. Here is my dataset now:

```
        Country         Date        Confirmed   Deaths  Recovered
2600    Mainland China  2020-02-28  410.0       7.0     257.0
2601    Iran            2020-02-28  388.0       34.0    73.0
2602    Mainland China  2020-02-28  337.0       3.0     279.0
2603    Mainland China  2020-02-28  318.0       6.0     277.0
2604    Mainland China  2020-02-28  296.0       1.0     235.0
...     ...             ...         ...         ...     ...
2695    US              2020-02-25  1.0         0.0     1.0
2696    US              2020-02-24  0.0         0.0     0.0
2697    US              2020-02-24  0.0         0.0     0.0
2698    US              2020-02-24  0.0         0.0     0.0
2699    Mainland China  2020-02-29  66337.0     2727.0  28993.0
```

I want to summarize all the Confirmed, Deaths and Recovered values if the values in the Country and Date columns are the same.

So for instance, in the rows 2600, 2602, 2603, 2604 the values in the columns Country and Date match so I want to combine these rows and summarize the Confirmed, Deaths and Recovered columns separately. Which should give the following row:

```
 2600    Mainland China  2020-02-28  1361.0       17.0     1048.0
```

What I have so far:

```
duplicateRowsDF = df[df.duplicated(['Country', 'Date'])]
duplicateRowsDF
```

Hope somebody can help me out, preferably with, but not limited to, Pandas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `groupby`? If you do this:

```
df.groupby(by=['Country', 'Date']).sum()
```

All your rows with same country and date will be grouped into only one column with the sum of all values in each column.

Comment: Yes great, that worked. I changed it to this: df= df.groupby(by=['Date', 'Country']).sum()  so that Everything is grouped by the date. Thank you!